# Discrete Math Validating Argument Using Deduction Method

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

I am lost trying prove that the expression below is a valid argument using the deduction method (that is using equivalences and rules of inference in a proof sequence).

(∃x)[A(x)∧B(x)]→(∃x)A(x)∧(∃x)B(x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [List of rules of inference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_rules_of_inference) or :

- Kenneth Rosen, [Discrete mathematics and its applications](https://books.google.it/books?id=cPRLAgAAQBAJ) (7th ed), pages 72 and 76 for the rules :

1) $(∃x)[A(x)∧B(x)]$ --- premise

2) $A(y)∧B(y)$ --- from 1) by *Existential Instantiation* : $y$ not occurring into 1)

3) $A(y)$ --- from 2) by *Simplification*

4) $B(y)$ --- from 2) by *Simplification* (or *Conjunction Elimination*)

5) $(∃x)A(x)$ --- from 3) by *Existential Generalization*

6) $(∃x)B(x)$ --- from 4) by *Existential Generalization*

7) $(∃x)A(x)∧(∃x)B(x)$ --- from 5) and 6) by *Adjunction* (or *Conjunction introduction*

> 8) $(∃x)[A(x)∧B(x)] \to (∃x)A(x)∧(∃x)B(x)$ --- from 1) and 8) by *Conditional Introduction*